# How to dynamically create a method or a setter in a class in Dart?

Tags: dart

Is it possible to dynamically add an instance method or a setter to an existing class, either from within this class or from outside of it?

Comment: it's not quite what you're asking, but you might use a delegate, or a List/Map of delegates to have this functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't add a *real member* to a class.

I said *real member* because you can simulate such feature with [noSuchMethod()](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/Object.html#noSuchMethod). Here a example :

```dart
@proxy
class A {
  final dynamicMethods = <Symbol, Function>{};

  noSuchMethod(Invocation i) {
    if (i.isMethod && dynamicMethods.containsKey(i.memberName)) {
      return Function.apply(dynamicMethods[i.memberName],
          i.positionalArguments, i.namedArguments);
    }
    return super.noSuchMethod(i);
  }
}

main() {
  final a = new A();
  a.dynamicMethods[#sayHello] = () => print('hello');
  a.sayHello();
}
```

In the future this could perhaps be possible. See this excerpt from [the article on Mirrors](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/reflection-with-mirrors/) :

> We’d like to support more powerful reflective features in the future. These would include *mirror builders*, designed to allow programs to extend and modify themselves, and a mirror-based debugging API as well.

Comment: can Expando http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/Expando.html used for this? 
I took a brief look a while ago but don't know what exactly it can do.

Comment: I suppose it's only for assigning values not for methods.